# Columns With Multiple Data Types in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U1zg.png)

I need to have percentage, currency and decimal values and text (String) in single column. I tried to create a measure but it didn't work.

Let me know what needs to be done.
#PowerBI

`Measure1 =  VAR VAL = SUMMARIZE('Sheet1',Sheet1[Indicator]) RETURN SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet1'[Entity]),"FY23 Net Operating Income Monthly Actual", FORMAT(VAL,"$0"))`

This code didn't work for me as it said cannot transform string data.

Comment: Short answer is that each column can only have one data type. If you need to store all kinds of data, maybe store it as text and convert as needed. But explain what your data is about. Something's missing from your description, I think.

Comment: Data contains, numbers, text and percentages. What I want to do is whenever I select a particular column as a filter, the corresponding column should show up. For example, If I select from indicator column a particular indicator which has value of text in the value column. It should just show text. Similarly for Percentage and currency values. @Pieter